# How do I encrypt/decrypt a password field in Odoo 9.0?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How do I encrypt this field before storing it in the database?

```
password = fields.Char(string="Password", required=True)
```

Do I use [auth_crypt](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/auth_crypt/auth_crypt.py)?

How do I store (encrypt) and retrieve (decrypt) this field? Do I need to use computed fields?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you should not store encrypted passwords because they can be decrypted when an attacker obtains access to the server.

Instead you should iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about 100ms, (the salt needs to be saved with the hash). Better to use functiions designed to do this such as password_hash, PBKDF2, bcrypt, etc. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

See OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_an_adaptive_one-way_function).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use odoo official encrypt module. after 8.0 onward odoo default encrypt password.

new field: password_crypt which store encoded protected password.

Use official way of pick password field in model file
and proper xml widget for form view.

[How to reset user's password via direct SQL for Odoo](https://snippetbucket.com/2016/02/odoo-set-password-odoo-hack-odoo-crack-hard-reset-odoo-login-odoo-forget-pass-word-abc-xyz/)